# How to neaten css shapes?

Tags: css, html

Please check out this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rr4GH/1/

As you can see its a round edge box with two triangles BUT the line in the centre dividing both triangles isn't straight. How can it be made so its straight?

ALSO the top right corner seems to be a bit undecided what colour it is, how can that be sorted?

html:

```
<div class="css-arrow-multicolor"></div>
```

css:

```
.css-arrow-multicolor {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: blue #ECB603 #ECB603 blue;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:15px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: It looks pretty good in Chrome.

Comment: looks pretty darn straight to me. What's the problem? consider posting a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: In IE9 too, although it seems to be 1px off in certain zoom percentages. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: The rounded corners are quite sharp anyway and don't have a nice anti aliasing. This will most certainly improve in future browsers, but for now, if you want it to look nice, smooth, and above all: the same in all browsers, you should still use images.

Comment: If you give `.css-arrow-multicolor` a width of 1px, the diagonal will straighten up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem... right in the middle it's one pixel off right?

If you use one color for one side and transparent for the other it gives you a straight line. Use two of them to accomplish the same effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/rr4GH/4/

Comment: Ah thanks! Just a quick one... if I wanted the top right corner and bottom left corder to NOT be rounded, how is that done?

Comment: remove the border-radius:; and use border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px;